# How to design email and username login

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two question about usernames and emails

**1. I judge username is a Email if '@' in username, and auth it follow:**

```
email_user = User.objects.get(email__iexact=username)
authenticate(username=email_user.username)
```

Is that a good way that you recommended? or you may have a better advice?
  I know a `AbstractBaseUser` can do it, but I think use `User` is more reasonable.

**2. Should I store the user's email within the `User.email` field?**

Imagine if I sign up a new user with:

```
username: '123'
email: '456@google.com'
```

and when I signup success, then I find that my email is wrong,
and now another user that email is '456@google.com' can't signup again.
I just want to a email is verified that can associate with the user.
what's your advice?

Comment: Do you want to write your own code for this?  Or do you just want a functioning login with email verification?

Comment: The class `User` inherits from the AbstractBaseUser class. You can create your own custom user class which will override the "base" django user model.

Comment: Django auth's user model's username field has a max length of 30 so setting it to the email field will never work, you need to make your own custom user model if you wish to have the email as a username

Comment: @Withnail you can input username or your email to the username, and if (username=username and password=password) or (email=username and password=password)  is True , you login success

Comment: @Sayse I just want to login with username or email as username..

Comment: Then you may need to write your own custom authentication method

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use email as your unique sign in key, it would save you a lot of trouble in future development of your website if you make a custom User model using AbstractBaseUser. *If you want i can post a sample working code*

In reference to your second question - You can use Cryptographic signing in Django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/signing/) to produce a key. Further send this key as a link (eg www.example.com/verify/:some_crypto_key:) and send it as a link to user's email address. This key will contain user id and time stamp. If you receive a request on that link, it means that email is legit. You may find a package that does a similar task maybe.

EDIT:
Implementation (short way) - As the user signups on your website, Immediately ask him/her to verify account using the link you have sent to the given email. If you do not receive a response from that email within a given time (say 20 mins), delete that user entry. This means that you can not let the user access your website until he/she verifies the account.

Flaw - Consider a situation where the user has submitted a wrong email. It is obvious that the user will never be able to verify it but for those 20 mins if co-incidentally the actual user with that same email tries to signup on your website, he won't be able to access. This is very unlikely. Also this user will receive an email from your website saying that user has signed-up on a website (so here you can provide another link, 'if this was not you, please click here' kind of thing)

Comment: If I use email as my unique sign in key, imagine that, if I use 123@google.com sign up successful, but the email '123@google.com' is yours. and now you can't sign up yourself account, and I can't verify the wrong Email. <br>I'am a bit confused, can you give me some code through any way.

Comment: There is a long way and hackish way to achieve this. However, let me first tell you the short way (which has a minor flaw), and if this suits you, you can go ahead with this.

Comment: May be I can do it like this: if you sign up with '123@google.com' and 'username', now you only can use 'username' login, unless you verify your  email. If another people sign up with same email and verify success, you won't be verify the email(in fact, if the email is not yours, you can't receive any verify Email), and should modify another email to bind.  : )

Comment: Yes sure. You can easily do this with django's current user model. Everything that i explained was for when username doesn't exist and email is the login key.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a burning desire to write your own [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user), which will let you replace the username field with the email, I would recommend using something like [Django AllAuth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth).  It includes email verification (as outlined in your question), and can be set to use email as username fairly easily.  It's a well established library with lots of support, and will be more immediately usable than rolling your own.

(That said - rolling your own is an illuminating experience, and RA123's point is the answer you should accept if you're going down that road.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have a at it. : )